# Javascript debugging stopped working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I recently installed IE11 and then had to roll back to IE9 for compatibility issues with an existing application - since doing that I can no longer debug javascript in Visual Studio 2010 - if I put a breakpoint in, it says

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

If I put in ***debugger;*** within the script, it will break but not in the VS it's running from, it asks me to open a new instance to debug in.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your default browser back to IE9 and launching the project with debugging. This should cause VS to attach to the IE process and if the symbols are available, you should be able to debug.